# In MongoDB, how would you write a query to search in an array of date ranges if their field exists?

Tags: mongodb

My query looks like this:

```
{
    $or: [
        {$and: [{field1: {$exists: true}},{field1: {$get: beginDate, $lte: endDate}}]}
        {$and: [{field2: {$exists: true}},{field2: {$get: beginDate, $lte: endDate}}]}
        {$and: [{field3: {$exists: true}},{field3: {$get: beginDate, $lte: endDate}}]}
    ]
}
```

and I get this error (I can't figure out what it means):

```
Error: Can't use $get with Date.
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no `$get` but `$gte`

```
$or: [
        {$and: [{field1: {$exists: true}},{field1: {$gte: beginDate, $lte: endDate}}]}
                                                     ^
        {$and: [{field2: {$exists: true}},{field2: {$get: beginDate, $lte: endDate}}]}
                                                     ^
        {$and: [{field3: {$exists: true}},{field3: {$get: beginDate, $lte: endDate}}]}
                                                     ^
    ]
```

Comment: Haha, yes, I was just about to try and remove my question as I just noticed this typo myself.  Thank you.